# formatting data for faceting in ggplot2 (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to accomplish something in ggplot2 that shouldn't be a big deal, but that blocks me somehow.

I need to import this xls file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/mydata.xls and format it so I can display 4 facetted line graphs (titled "m", "mNC", "d", "aSPL") like in this model drawed by myself (only showing the "mNC" facet, but the other one should be built on the same model):

[image: this is what I would like to get...]

Now, the trick, I think, is that the columns are named as such: "PE-GED-nMC", "GA-GED-nMC", "N1-GED-nMC", "N2-GED-nMC", etc. and I need to somehow tell R to arrange data according to parts of these column names. I think...

Does anyone have a clue about how to get from my data.xls to 4 faceted figures?

Cheers!

Comment: post the code that you have tried; also `facet_wrap()`

Comment: Sounds like you might need to reshape the data, but you didn't really give us much to work with. How did you make that mock up?

Comment: I haven't been able to try facet_grid() (or facet_wrap() for that matter) yet, as the data is probably not in the right shape, and I have no idea how to start reshaping it. I made the mock up simply by imagining what I want the figures to look at, I don't have much more to work with for now: just the raw data as the xls table, unfortunately... What else could I provide that could help you guys?

Comment: You will need to `melt` the data from wide format to long format.  The column headings form a new column.  You also need to split the column headings (i.e. the new variable in the long format) into 3 columns using `colsplit`.  All this is in the `reshape` (or `reshape2`) package, documentation here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf  Se how you get on and update your question with some specific questions and some headway on the problem you'll get more assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should deliver what you are looking for - applying melt as suggested by Matt. The grepl-function should help you parse the text labels. I did not know what the horizontal and the vertical categories really are so just gave them generic names.

Clearly the ifelse-constructs are somewhat cumbersome and may warrant a more elegant solution in a more complex setting.

```
require(reshape2)
#use melt to go from wide to long data
dataM = melt(data,c("nbr"))

#parse labels to identify vertical category and fill the value correspondingly
dataM$vertical = ifelse(grepl("GED",dataM$variable),"GED",ifelse(grepl("RAN",dataM$variable),"RAN",ifelse(grepl("EIG",dataM$variable),"EIG","BET")))
#parse labels to identify horizontal category and fill the value correspondingly
dataM$horizontal = ifelse(grepl("PE",dataM$variable),"PE",ifelse(grepl("GA",dataM$variable),"GA",ifelse(grepl("N1",dataM$variable),"N1","N2")))
#parse label to identify category
dataM$category = ifelse(grepl("mNC",dataM$variable),"mNC",ifelse(grepl("aSPL",dataM$variable),"aSPL",ifelse(grepl("_d",dataM$variable),"d","m")))

#create ggplot objects with sub-setted data
p1 = ggplot(dataM[dataM$category=="mNC",],aes(x=nbr,y=value))
p1 = p1 + geom_line()
#face_grid creates the panels that you are looking for (usage is vertical_categories ~ horizontal_categories)
p1 = p1 + facet_grid(vertical~horizontal)
p1

p2 = ggplot(dataM[dataM$category=="aSPL",],aes(x=nbr,y=value))
p2 = p2 + geom_line()
p2 = p2 + facet_grid(vertical~horizontal)
p2

p3 = ggplot(dataM[dataM$category=="d",],aes(x=nbr,y=value))
p3 = p3 + geom_line()
p3 = p3 + facet_grid(vertical~horizontal)
p3

p4 = ggplot(dataM[dataM$category=="m",],aes(x=nbr,y=value))
p4 = p4 + geom_line()
p4 = p4 + facet_grid(vertical~horizontal)
p4
```

Comment: It works wonderfully! I'm learning a lot with your answer, thanks so much!

Comment: Just wanted to add:
If you want to combine the plots you can use You can use grid.arrange() from gridExtra package. For a 2x2 panel the code would then be:

`grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2)`

more on that: http://is-r.tumblr.com/post/34628702940/ggtutorial-day-2-grid-arrange