# large dataset and faceting in ggplot2 (r)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been helped by @CMichael a couple of weeks ago when I was trying to work with faceting in ggplot2 ([formatting data for faceting in ggplot2 (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028999/formatting-data-for-faceting-in-ggplot2-r)). Starting from his solution, I now need to display scatter plots using a slightly different data format, and I end up with strange results.

Let me show you my code (the csv should download automatically, please let me know if it doesn't. Warning though: it's about 2mb):

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

md = read.csv(file="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/rob-136.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
dM = melt(md,c("id"))

#parse labels to identify "order" category and fill the value correspondingly
dM$order = ifelse(grepl("GED",dM$variable),"GED","NAR")

#parse labels to identify "Nm" category and fill the value correspondingly
dM$Nm = ifelse(grepl("FS",dM$variable),"FS",ifelse(grepl("VE",dM$variable),"VE",ifelse(grepl("N2",dM$variable),"N2","SW")))

#parse label to identify "category"
dM$category = ifelse(grepl("m", dM$variable),"m",
                     ifelse(grepl("mC",dM$variable),"mC",
                            ifelse(grepl("d",dM$variable),"d", 
                                   ifelse(grepl("nR",dM$variable),"nR","aSPL")))
                     )

# plot facet grid
p = ggplot(dM[dM$category=="d",],aes(x= dM[dM$category=="nR",]$value,y=dM[dM$category=="d",]$value))
p = p + scale_y_continuous(name="d")+ scale_x_continuous(name="nR") + xlim(0,136)
p = p + facet_grid(order~Nm)+ ggtitle("Title")
p = p + stat_bin2d(bins=50)
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))
p = p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100))
p = p + theme(legend.position="none")
p
```

[image]

My problem is as follow: all required scatterplots are correctly made (I *think* they are correct anyway), but the positions of the plots in the grid are all messed up.

Here is where the plots should be. It looks like there is a pattern here...
[image]

Q1: Is there something obviously wrong in the code? It is quite likely my data manipulation or call for faceting are completely off... Would someone be able to troubleshot it for me?

Q2: Quite besides the point, but well... What's the correct way to display "nR" at the x axis?

Cheers!

Comment: `positions of the plots in the grid are all messed up` can you elaborate?  Q2 - `+ xlab("nR")`

Comment: perhaps you can add the `scales = "free"` option to this line `p = p + facet_grid(order ~ Nm, scales = "free")+ ggtitle("Title")` Take a look at the [documentation for other options](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html).

Comment: Hey Martín Bel, Scales = "free" doesn't seem to help. Thanks for xlab, @Tyler Rinker, I'll try and elaborate on where scatter plots should be... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you can subset the data first. Such as: `df <- dM[dM$category %in% "d", ]` and then create a new "value" variable for nR such as: 
`df$nR_value <- dM[dM$category %in% "nR", ]$value`.

Comment: Hey Martin, it seems to give exactly the same rasult

Comment: As Ista is alluding to below, you should basically never be using `[` or `$` when you map variables to aesthetic inside `aes()`. It should always just be `aes(x = variable,...)` or some simple function of the variable name.

Comment: take a look at [hadley's tidy data paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) in order to get a clearer idea of how your data should be in order to use ggplot2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things will go much more smoothly if you arrange your data in a way that corresponds to the variables you want to plot rather than trying to subset your data to extract the values you want. An example is below, along with a replacement for your nested ifelse section which I found hard to follow.

```
dM = melt(md,c("id"))
# split variable out into its components
dM <- cbind(dM,
            colsplit(dM$variable,
                     pattern = "_",
                     names = c("Nm", "order", "category"))) 
# no longer need variable, as it is represented by the combination of Nm, order, and category
dM$variable <- NULL
# rearrange putting category in the columns
dM <- dcast(dM, ... ~ category, value.var = "value")

# plot
p = ggplot(dM, aes(x=nR ,y=d))
```

From there you can continue as before.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much! I need to get my head around it now... :) this is really great...